# Error: 'Method Not Found' in Google my business API get all reviews endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-business-profile-api

I am building an application that enables the user to reply to a review from google search & google maps, collectively to google business.
I have created a GCP project and followed all the steps given in the documentation. As of October 2022, there is a migration process going on in google business APIs. for fetching the business details and location details, v1 needs to be used, and for working with reviews, v4 needs to be used. v1 is working fine for all the supported API endpoints. but for v4, getting the reviews is throwing this 'Method not found an error in the google OAuth playground
[image: Image 1]

Every required API in the GCP is enabled.

this is the endpoint that I am trying to access: -
https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/106808491700086415691/locations/4502850563646255854/reviews

An early reply is always appreciated.

Thank you,
Siddhraj